# Facebook SDK for Unity on Android tries to login on FB.init without calling FB.login

Tags: android, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm having trouble running the Facebook Unity SDK on Android devices. Even without running "FB.Login()", the login page is called. Everything runs as expected on iOS or web player. Is there any workaround fot this? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using the latest version of the Facebook SDK, version 3.1.2, for Unity version 4.2.

Comment: Hi @lguatemi, we have a new SDK for this which is in the process of getting reviewed for push. If you're feeling brave, feel free to grab it here and give us feedback: unite-friend-smash.parseapp.com/FacebookSDK.unitypackage

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @aaron! All doing fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed on new release in the process of getting reviewed: unite-friend-smash.parseapp.com/FacebookSDK.unitypackage.

Comment: how live here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/ let me know if you have any problems, and thanks for trying this out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have using loginBehavior!

i fix it when i exclude this part of my code

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location","user_birthday", "user_likes"));
//      authButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```